# Why do I keep getting error that my model does not contain a definition for another model and yet it does

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use eager loading to join 3 tables, the first two tables have no problem but when I try to Include the 3rd table joined from the 2nd table, I keep getting a compile error that says -

> '`List<Qualification>`' does not contain a definition for
> 'QualificationName' and no accessible extension method
> 'QualificationName' accepting a first argument of type
> '`List<Qualification>`' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

here is my code

```
public class User
{  
    [Key][Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public List<Qualification> Qualifications { get; set; }
}

public class Qualification
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("QualificationStatus")]
    public QualificationStatus QualificationStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("QualificationLevel")]
    public QualificationLevel QualificationLevel { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("QualificationName")]
    public QualificationName QualificationName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Upload")]
    public Upload Upload { get; set; }

}

public class QualificationName
    {
        [Key][Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

for models and my EF code is as followes

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUserProfile(string UserId)
    {
        var user = await RepositoryContext.User.Include(c => c.Qualifications)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.QualificationName)
                .Where(c => c.Id == UserId)
                .Select(c => c.Qualifications)
                .Select(c => c.QualificationName)
                .ToListAsync();
        
        return user;
    }
```

I have a red line below Qualification name that shows the error when I hover over it on the line

```
.Select(c => c.QualificationName)
```

in the EF code

Comment: Hint: read the error message carefully. A *list* of qualifications doesn't contain a qualification name - an individual qualification does.

Comment: A `[Key]` is always `[Required]`. Also, what are you trying to achieve by putting `[MaxLength(3)]` on `int Id`? Why is `Notes` the only string you give a `[MaxLength]`? You don't need `[Required]` for a `DateTime` as it's a value type (non nullable). And using e.g. `[ForeignKey("QualificationStatus")]` on a property `QualificationStatus` of type `QualificationStatus` also doesn't make much sense

Comment: @atiyar I used sql to create the tables.

Comment: @JHBonarius much noted I will make the modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code like below(use `SelectMany`):

```
 var user = await RepositoryContext.User.Include(c => c.Qualifications)
            .ThenInclude(d => d.QualificationName)
            .Where(c => c.Id == UserId)
            .SelectMany(c => c.Qualifications)
            .Select(c => c.QualificationName)
            .ToListAsync();
```

The last data found will be of type `QualificationName`.

If you only want to get user,you just need use this code:

```
  var user = await RepositoryContext.User.Include(c => c.Qualifications)
            .ThenInclude(d => d.QualificationName)
            .Where(c => c.Id == UserId)
            .ToListAsync();
```

**Edit**(Not sure if your database relationship is correct, you can try my updated code)

```
var user = await  _context.Users.Select(b => new User
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            CreatedDate = b.CreatedDate,
            EmailAddress=b.EmailAddress,
            FirstName=b.FirstName,
            LastName=b.LastName,
            Qualifications = b.Qualifications.Select(s => new Qualification 
            { 
                CreatedDate=s.CreatedDate,
                StartDate=s.StartDate,
                EndDate=s.EndDate,
                Id=s.Id,
                Notes=s.Notes,
                QualificationName = s.QualificationName 
            }).ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is "why"?

Comment: The reason in the error message is already clear.

Comment: I have done that, now the return type gives me `List<QualificationName` instead of `User`

Comment: Hi @SmithWalikoMsiska What type of data do you want to obtain?

Comment: If you only want to return to user then why continue to select?

Comment: @Yinqiu I used someone else's code example, since I kept getting the same error when I dont include the select statements

Comment: If you only want get the user,just use `await RepositoryContext.User.Include(c => c.Qualifications).ThenInclude(d => d.QualificationName).Where(c => c.Id == UserId).TolistAsync()`.

Comment: I just tried this and got the following error

Comment: >System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'd.QualificationName' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.

Comment: Hi @SmithWalikoMsiska Not sure if your database relationship is correct, you can try my updated cod

Comment: I am still getting an error  -  > Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'UserId1'.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use [`efcore`](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/install-entity-framework-core.aspx) and how to create relationships correctly.